# How to restart udevd on RH/CentOS system?

Tags: centos, redhat, centos5, udev

For udevd there is no init.d script and manual page is not indicating how to restart it either. The process is holding a deleted file (lsof shows) and I need to release it by restarting udevd.

How to reload/restart udevd on CentOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct there is no init script. To restart the udevd run the following command:

```
# /sbin/start_udev
```

Hope that works!

Comment: Hope that works? :) inspires confidence!

Comment: This is the answer. Kudos @prateek61. (Though I would personally use a `killall udevd` command first.)